# Regex to select something between a #OnlinePopup and _

Tags: regex

Can someone show me a regex to select **#OnlinePopup_AFE53E2CACBF4D8196E6360D4DDB6B70** its okay to assume `#OnlinePopup`

```
~DCTM~dctm://aicpcudev/37004e1f8000219e?DMS_OBJECT_SPEC=RELATION_ID#OnlinePopup_AFE53E2CACBF4D8196E6360D4DDB6B70_11472026_1214836152225_6455280574472127786
```

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: The following is .NET Regex syntax, modify for your flavour.

The following:

```
#[^_]+_[^_]+
```

will match:

- Hash
- One or more characters until an underscore
- Underscore
- One or more characters until an underscore

If the first bit is constant, and you want to be more specific you could use:

```
#OnlinePopup_[A-F0-9]+
```

This will match

- ## OnlinePopup_ (exactly)
- One or more hex characters until a non Hex character

Comment: parsing "\#[^\_]+\_[^\_]+" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.

Comment: Sorry, try removing the \ in \_. Regex languages have little variations like this.

Comment: Were you getting the "Unrecognized escape sequence" because the compiler was trying interpreting escape sequences? I usually put an literal (@) marker at the start of regex strings: @"\#blah". Otherwise you need to double escape your \'s

Comment: The hash and underscore aren't metacharacters in regular expressions.  You should not escape them.  The error about \_ comes from the regex engine.  .NET doesn't allow the underscore to be escaped.

Comment: @Jan Interestingly it does not care about the \#. I can leave it on or off, but it throws a tantrum on \_. Post changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply matching anything between the first '#' and the first or last '_' will not work for your example since the string that you want returned has an underscore in it. If all the text that you want to match has only **one** underscore in it, you could use this regex:

```
/(#[^_]+_[^_]+)/
```

This matches an octothorpe (#), followed by two strings that do not contain an underscore, seperated by a single underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Something a little simpler:

```
(\#OnlinePopup_.*?)_
```

Assuming your text starts with # and ends with _